# Does Stanford University conduct research into psychic spies?

Tags: esp, psychics

Ron White of Brain Athlete [reports](http://brainathlete.com/psychics-counterintelligence-real-xfiles/):

> Stanford Research Institute (SRI) has been carrying out secret psychic investigations using remote viewing for 20 years, checking into our ability to experience and describe distant events blocked from ordinary perception. This research was supported by the CIA, NASA and many other government organizations, and was used for gathering intelligence about world-wide targets including China, the USSR, and Iran, during the Cold War.

I have heard similar stories of covert training of psychic students. Is this true?

Comment: Related video: [Banned TEDTalk about Psychic Abilities | Russell Targ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBl0cwyn5GY)

Answer (score 6):

The [Stanford Research Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRI_International) was established by Stanford University in 1946 as a research innovation centre. It started a number of important developments such as the computer mouse and inkjet printing. It separated from Stanford Uni in 1970 and became SRI International.

Alongside their legitimate research, SRI also became involved in some more esoteric projects, some of which were sponsored by the CIA. These included "research" into remote viewing and telekinesis. They also tested some subjects such as Uri Geller.

The parapsychology research at SRI finished in 1991, and their present website does not indicate any outlandish projects. At that time their psychic programme was transferred to the [Stargate Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Project), until its demise and declassification in 1995

One of the main proponents of Stargate was Maj Gen [Albert Stubblebine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Stubblebine), whose "research" was immortalised in the movie "[The Men who Stare at Goats](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/men_who_stare_at_goats/)".

So yes, the US military and other departments engaged in psychic nonsense. And , of course, nothing ever came of any of these projects.

[SRI International](https://www.sri.com/) still exists, but their activities now seem to be limited to legitimate research.

Comment: You may call it "nonsense".  But we didn't know it was until it was tested, right?

Comment: @GEdgar True, but many people have been calling it nonsense for centuries. And the believers refuse to give up regardless. The Rhine Institute is still pretending there's "something"...